# Can't find a specific tag using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

The HTML code:

```
<a id="id47" title="textA"
onclick="var wcall=wicketAjaxGet('?wicket:interface=:1blablabla')" 
href="#">

<span class="icon" style="background-image: url('folder/background.png')"></span>

<span>textB</span>
```

I want to use Selenium webdriver to locate and click the icon above. Normally, I would do this using the ID, but unfortunately, the program keeps changing these IDs for no apparent reason, so I have to locate the element using either the title (textA) or Span (textB)

I came up with the following:

```
public void performclick() throws Throwable {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text('textB')]")).click();
}
```

or

```
public void performclick() throws Throwable {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text('textA')]")).click();
}
```

and any deviations on these.
Everytime I run the scenario, it gives nothing back. What am I not figuring right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try cssSelectors as well,

```
css = a[title='textA']
```

or

If some part of your id remains constant,for instance,in your case if `id47` changes to `id48` or `id200` and so on...you can use contains(,i.e, *****) or starts with (,i.e, **^**) **:**

```
css = a[id*='id'][title='textA']
```

or

```
css = a[id^='id'][title='textA']
```

For span (textB),the following would work **:**

```
css = span.icon + span
```

Here **+** is used to locate **following sibling**.

Comment: I never realized that css could find a sibling (like XPath can).  Is there a way to get a parent element (XPath uses '..') ?  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @djangofan, no, and the `+` is a CSS3 selector and thus won't work in IE8 and below.

Comment: @djangofan, though it isn't native.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//*[@title='textA']
```

or

```
//*[text()='textB']
```

Comment: `//a[@title='textA']` will be more efficient.

Comment: @Kama, do you mind me editing? or you want to post your answer (I fine with that)? I based my answer on OP's `"//*[contains(text('textA')]"` but indeed testing `//a[@title='textA']` and `//span[text()='textB']` is better